# C, Trouble getting size of array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, sizeof

I'm trying to get the number of elements in an array of structs so I can pass it into another function. Struct:

```
struct info{
    char string1[30];
    float float1;
    int int1;
    char string2[30];
};
```

Section I'm trying to run:

```
void function1(){
    struct info* temp = build();
    printf("flag: %lu %lu %lu\n", sizeof(temp), sizeof(temp[0]), sizeof(temp)/sizeof(temp[0]));
    sortFloat(temp, sizeof(temp)/sizeof(temp[0]), 1);
    free(temp);
}
```

build() returns an array of structs after reading in data from a file where each line will be a struct in the array.  I'm having trouble passing the size of the array into sortFloat().  The print line returns

```
flag: 8 72 0
```

when there are only two lines in the data file.  Hard coding that argument as 2 makes the whole program work correctly.  Why is this method of counting the elements of the array of structs not?

Comment: `sizeof(temp) ` will give you size of pointer variable not the size of whole array.

Comment: build() returns NOT an array (of everything), in C you cannot return an array from a function, it's ever a pointer to the first element of an array. Pointer and Array are not the same in C.

Answer (score 3):

```
sizeof(temp)
```

will not evaluate to the number of elements in the array. It will evaluate to just the size of the pointer.

If you need the size of the array, you can do this:

Change the signature of `build` to:

```
struct info* build(int* sizePtr);
```

Make sure that `sizePtr` is appropriately set in the implementation.

Then, call it using:

```
int size;
struct info* temp = build(&size);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are thinking of as an array is more precisely just a pointer to the first element. How many elements follow the first element cannot be known to `function1()`. Only the function `build()` knows how many elements were read and how much memory was dynamically allocated to store those elements.

The only solution is to get the `build()` function to also pass back the number of elements read from the file. One way to do this is to send the address of an `int` variable to `build(int *countp)` and have `build(int *countp)` store the count into this `int` using either `++*countp;` as it reads each element or `*countp = n;` where `n` is a different variable in which `build(...)` maintains the count.

Answer (score 1):

Because `temp` is not an array. It is a pointer. So calling `sizeof` on it will return the size of the pointer.

It might be hard to understand, but in C, arrays (*real* arrays, not pointers) are best regarded as *value types* that are quite tricky to pass around by value. Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays.

`sizeof` is an operator for determining the size of memory occupied by a *value*. That is why, when applied to an *array*, it returns the size of the array, and when applied to a pointer - just the size of the pointer.

What you're creating and returning from `build()` is most likely a dynamically-allocated (via `malloc` or friends) buffer of memory. In this case, it was never a *real* array to begin with! It is just a pointer to a chunk of memory on the heap. This chunk of memory is not one value, and its size cannot be determined using `sizeof` like that. So you've got no choice but to count the number of allocated `struct`s and get that information to the caller.